# Where can I find a list of the features from Korn and C shells incorporated by Bash?

Tags: bash, csh, ksh

I would like to have some documentation about the features from Korn (ksh) and the C (csh) shells incorporated in the Bash command language interpreter. A exhaustive list of commands would be great. Thanks

Or is the legacy from the Korn and C shells mostly archi-structural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [The reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) should help but you may also need [this old document](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_toc.html).

You may be looking for the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/), which lists and exhaustively describes *all* features of Bash, including [all built-in commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) ("builtins"). Both Bash and Ksh are Bourne-style shells, and the Bash reference manual lists [builtins from the Bourne shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) and [builtins provided in addition to those](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) separately.

> Or is the legacy from the Korn and C shells mostly archi-structural?

This is somewhat true. Many of the features in Bash that were present in the C Shell or the Korn Shell are features other than the presence of a specifically named built-in command.

Note that Bash and Ksh are both Bourne-style shells, and Csh isn't. Bash and Ksh are far more similar to one another than either is to Csh.

There are some  sources that provide feature comparisons between shells, including Bash, Ksh, and Csh, such as [the table in this appendix](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/x7369.html). Please be aware, that's not official Bash documentation, it may not be complete, and it may not have been written with the newest versions of Bash in mind.

**For an *official* comparison**, I recommend [Bash Features: Overview Documentation for Bash](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_toc.html). You should be aware that this document is from 1994 and it describes Bash 1.14. (In contrast, [current versions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash) of Ubuntu use Bash 4.3 or 4.4. Run `bash --version` or `apt list bash` to check what you have.) However, because you're asking about Bash *history*, this is reasonable.

That document has detailed sections on [**C-Shell Style Features**](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_2.html#SEC9) and [**Korn-Shell Style Features**](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_3.html#SEC14). This should provide the explicit comparisons you are looking for. It also has sections on [Bourne Shell Style Features](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_1.html#SEC1) and [Bash Specific Features](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_4.html#SEC20) (and several other topics).